# How can I do a context menu with logo on the left side

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I've looking for 4 hours how can I do a context menu with logo. I mean something which looks like daemon tools context menu.

For these who dont know how it looks like:
[image: Daemon Tools Lite Context Menu]

Is there any option to do it in simple way in XAML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to adjust ContextMenu's [control template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744758.aspx).

Just copy the whole thing and and wrap this StackPanel in Grid or DockPanel to which you add the image:

```
<StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
```

Once you understand and learn not to fear control templates, they are really not a big deal. No C# necessary, all is pure XAML.

[Brief tutorial.](http://www.wpftutorial.net/templates.html)

Comment: Really I dont know how can I use it in MenuItem. Are you sure if that works?

Comment: @nosbor I edited the answer a bit, I meant ContextMenu, not MenuItem of course :). Copy the whole template as it is on MSDN and set it as value of your ContextMenu's ControlTemplate property. Then do the changes into it and you are done.